# how to add more than 1000 values with NOT IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have comma delimited id's that I want to use in NOT IN clause.. 
I'm using oracle 11g.

```
select * from table where ID NOT IN (1,2,3,4,...,1001,1002,...)
```

results in

```
ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000
```

I don't want to use temp table. am trying considering doing this

```
select * from table1 where ID NOT IN (1,2,3,4,…,1000) AND 
ID NOT IN (1001,1002,…,2000)
```

Is there any other better workaround to this issue?

Comment: No..id's are not predictable.

Comment: Where the values of those IDs come from?

Comment: What is the motivation for not using a temp table?

Comment: And where does the SQL for above query live? Client side? Inside a stored procedure, function, package? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 9):

You said you don't want to, but: use a temporary table. That's the correct solution here.

Query parsing is expensive in Oracle, and that's what you'll get when you put thousands of identifiers into a giant blob of SQL. Also, there are [ill-defined limits](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:41742083561301) on query length that you're going to hit. Doing an anti-JOIN against a table, on the other hand... Oracle is good at that. Bulk loading data into a table, Oracle is good at that too. Use a temp table.

Limiting `IN` to a thousand entries is a sanity check. The fact that you're hitting it means you're trying to do something insane.

Comment: "The fact that you're hitting it means you're trying to do something insane." Well put.

Comment: I largely agree with your analysis but I think a temporary table is the wrong solution.  The overhead of populating temporary tables rules them out for many scenarios.  Passing an array - a PL/SQL collection - would probably be a better idea.

Comment: If you've got more than 1000 values it seems likely to me that they're coming from Somewhere Else in your database - perhaps a query of some sort? - I suspect there isn't a user out there industriously typing in numbers - in which case an anti-join against that query might be a reasonable solution.

Comment: I agree, but I decided not to pursue that line of reasoning. The poster stated he has "comma delimited id's" that are "not predictable"; he just wants to know how to get around the 1000-`IN` limit, so that's all I chose to answer. And even if they were coming from outside the database, they probably correspond to some domain concept which *does* belong in the database...

Answer (score 0):

Jump out of the question, can you combine the SQL to get more than 1000 IDs with this SQL. That's the better way to simplify your SQLs.

Answer (score 0):

It's insane.

But you can probably try to select from select:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN (1,2,3,4,...,1000))
WHERE ID NOT IN (1001,1002,…,2000)
```

Make as many levels as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MINUS`, the opposite to `UNION

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
MINUS 
SELECT T.* FROM TABLE T,TABLE2 T2 WHERE T.ID = T2.ID
```

This represents registers on table `T` which id not in `table2 t2`